# Is there any way to write to files faster? (windows)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I make an application that must be able to process and store a lot of measurements.
There can be up to 129600 measurements and every measurement can have 1499 values.
All data is stored in an array, each column is a measurement.

After 10 measurements I save the data from the array to a file. Because if the application crashes, then i haven't lost all data.

In the beginning of the measurements, saving to the file only takes a few millieseconds. But when i am at measurement 200, it already takes 13 seconds. The time to save to the file keeps increasing. This makes sense, of course, because the array is getting bigger.

I can choose to only save every 50 or 100 measurements. But saving to the file will still take a long time.

Below you can see what the data in the file looks like:

```
Frequency(Hz);S21(dB)_1;S21(dB)_2
10000000;-42.87726786;-35.66746585
79950000;-60.5887682;-63.55421833
149900000;-84.56555597;-74.36793049
219850000;-76.71335093;-80.68063652
289800000;-68.96360042;-68.41861962
359750000;-71.24272337;-74.90287556
429700000;-78.65528362;-75.50614099
...
...
13860100000;-85.80839142;-84.03051407
13930050000;-79.31238317;-82.87468675
14000000000;-88.9003575;-75.48071161
```

**Is there a possibility to work in a different way, In such way that it takes less time to save?**

The code below converts the array to a large string.
measurementArrayToSave is a 2D array where each measurement data is added.

```
        private string StringToSave() // Create a large string from the array.
        {
            // Create a file to write to.
            string writeToFile = "";
            writeToFile = writeToFile + "Frequency(Hz)"; // Title is depending on the number of measurements.
            for (int titles = 0; titles < (numberOfMeasurements); titles++)
            {
                writeToFile = writeToFile + ";S21(dB)_" + (titles + 1).ToString() + " ";
            }
            writeToFile = writeToFile + ";Average" + "\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < (Points + 1); i++) // write array with measurements to string
            {
                int column = 0;
                if (i == Points)
                {
                    writeToFile = writeToFile + "Average"; // Set name "Average" on the last line
                    column = 1;
                }
                for (; column < (numberOfMeasurements + 2); column++)
                {
                    if (column == 0)
                    {
                        writeToFile = writeToFile + measurementArrayToSave[column, i].ToString().Replace(",", ".");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        writeToFile = writeToFile + ";" + measurementArrayToSave[column, i].ToString().Replace(",", ".");
                    }
                }
                writeToFile = writeToFile + "\n";
            }
            return writeToFile;
        }
```

The code below save the string to a file.

```
        private void SaveMeasurementStirrerAutomatic() // automatic save without dialogBox
        {
            // Full name will depend on date and time.
            string path = @"..\\measurementFiles\\" + textBoxName.Text +"_"+ thisDay.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss") + ".txt";

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Delete(path);
            }

            string writeToFile = StringToSave(); // call StringToSave()
            File.WriteAllText(path, writeToFile); // write string to file.
            labelStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { labelStatus.Text = "Data is saved!"; });               
        }
```

Comment: Are your rewriting the whole file every time, or only appending the new lines?

Comment: Do you always completely recreate the file or do you just append to it? [Edit] the question and include the relevant code.

Comment: is rewrite the entire file. I actually write the array to a large string first, then I write that entire string to a file.@MichaëlHompus

Comment: Is there a need to do that, i.e. can previous readings change? If not then just append instead of writing all of it again and again.

Comment: @stickybit previous readings can't change.

Comment: @techgirl2000, if you edit your question with the requested code snippet, It will be much better for future references of this question+answers.

Comment: from where are you reading the data from? If you reading it from some permanent storage then you could read it in chunks and process them or you read all at once and process them and save all of them at once. Reading everything at once might not help if your data is huge.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya I read the data from a measuring instrument. Every time a measurement takes place, data is added to the array. After every 10 measurements I save the data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

@techgirl2000 you are probably using the entire history on every single "Save" operation.

You better use that in-memory array as a temporary buffer. i.e. the data in-memory should be "appended" to the file, AND cleared once the save is successful.

```
    private void SaveMeasurementStirrerAutomatic() // automatic save without dialogBox
    {
        // Full name will depend on date and time.
        string path = @"..\\measurementFiles\\" + textBoxName.Text +"_"+ thisDay.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss") + ".txt";

        // Create the file, only if needed
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            string headers = HeadersToSave(); // Get the first line (Headers)
            File.WriteAllText(path, headers); // write string to file.
        }

        // append new lines
        string writeToFile = StringToSave(); // call StringToSave()
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
        {
            sw.Write(writeToFile); // not sure about this
        }
        //TODO: clear the array in memory

        labelStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { labelStatus.Text = "Data is saved!"; });               
    }
```

Now you need to split the StringToSave() into another function with only the header line

```
    private string HeadersToSave() // Create a large string from the array.
    {
        // Create a file to write to.
        string writeToFile = "Frequency(Hz)"; // Title is depending on the number of measurements.
        for (int titles = 0; titles < (numberOfMeasurements); titles++)
        {
            writeToFile = writeToFile + ";S21(dB)_" + (titles + 1).ToString() + " ";
        }
        writeToFile = writeToFile + ";Average" + "\n";
        return writeToFile;
     }
     // ...
```

If you can't clear the data, then use a marker on every row to confirm if that specific line was appended.

Comment: When I look on the internet, I find different methods. But all the code I find is based on first reading the line and then writing it back with the added data.
Is there a way to add data to the end of a line without having to read it back first?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [File.AppendText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-5.0) method:

```
    // This text is always added, making the file longer over time
    // if it is not deleted.
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("This");
        sw.WriteLine("is Extra");
        sw.WriteLine("Text");
    }
```

Comment: Does File.AppendText not make sure that the text is added at the end of the file? Or am I wrong?
The intention is that the data is next to the previous data. Not under the previous data.

Comment: @techgirl2000 files are just sequences of bytes. "Under" and "later" are the same thing